# acessing symbols dynamically through a gedit box using getsymbol function

Tags: r, gwidgets

I  had tried   a little  weird  way  of  accessing  symbols from  "YAHOO.FINANCE"   in   my   GUI   which is made  in   `gwidgets` Here is an example:

```
library(FuzzyToolkitUoN)
library(splines)
library(plyr)
library(Cairo)
library(cairoDevice)
library(gWidgets2)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(e1071)
library(RGtk2)
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
library(xts)

tbl[5,1] <- glabel("ENTER SYMBOL:-", cont = tbl)

tbl[5,2] <- gedit("", cont = tbl, coerce.with = as.character)

BSS <- function(h,...)
{    
  options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
  data <- new.env()
  getSymbols(svalue(tbl[5, 2]), env = data, auto.assign = TRUE)
  options("getSymbols.warning4.0" = FALSE)
  ashdata1 <- data.frame(tbl[5, 2])
}
```

I could not get those symbols from the `getSymbol` function. Can anyone show me some way how to access this symbols dynamically, such that the users can specify any symbols and could access those data in a click of a button?

Comment: Where are the library calls for the non-default packages, not to mention whatever website this may depend upon.?

Comment: Can  u  elaborate  ,  I  m new to R  language ............

Comment: None of those function are in the base packages.

Comment: I had mentioned the packages like  ,Quantmod ,  TTR ,xts  ,and all  ,but  didnt  mentioned here ..............

Comment: You think this is in some sort of chat room thread and that we are all reading your mind?

Comment: Can  you  guide me a bit ............:)

Comment: I was trying to but you seem to be rather resistant.

Comment: Sorry  for the in convenience ,  but  if  you  are intended  to  help  ,please  do  ,otherwise thanks  a lot   for  showing  interest in  my  post ..............:)

Comment: Edit button on the SO interface... use it. Edit your question to include the library calls for the packages that contain the functions you are using.

Comment: I m new  to  this  forum  olso  ,and to  R  olso  , u  r from  4  years  ,  u  can tolerate  a  bit mistakes right ............., I hope  you  will help  me  without any  ego  ,  i  didnt  mentioned  everything  to  not   jumble  the codes  ...............thats  my interest ............sry   again for the inconvenience  caused ..............:)

Comment: Ok  will do  it  ..........

Comment: I  hope  now  its  a little bit readable .........:)

Comment: main   packages are  Quantmod and  xts .............

Comment: Your `BSS` function is missing a return value.

Comment: What  should  i  return  a  integer  value or a character value ..........?